# how to for loop inside quote mark in R

Tags: r, for-loop, quote

I am trying to loop like this.

```
 Ob.df<-data.frame()
 Pt.df<-data.frame()

 for(i in 1:10){
 AE.rf@models$PA$rf$`i`@evaluation$training@observed  ->Ob.df[,i]
 AE.rf@models$PA$rf$`i`@evaluation$training@predicted ->Pt.df[,i]
 }
```

however, the i goes inside quote mark ( `i` ) and it does not loop. 
how to fix this issue?
Thanks for your any help.

Comment: Try this `[[i]]`

Comment: Sorry, it did not work.